# httpclient.execute(httppost) doesn't work？

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, httpclient

I use httpclient to post img to website. 
But I have tucked it into httpclient.execute(httppost).

In my local environment , I run it perfect. But when i publish project to SinaAppEngine（Java Local IO

restricted）->[***sae***](http://sae.sina.com.cn/) ,execute method doesn't work because code like this:

***reqEntity.addPart("image", byteArrayBody);***

**(Stringbody run normally )**

My sample code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://r.catchoom.com/v1/search");

ByteArrayBody byteArrayBody = new ByteArrayBody(imgByte, "test.jpg");

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

reqEntity.addPart("image", byteArrayBody);

httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Define doesn't work. Do you get an exception? If so post it.

Comment: I don't get any error in sae,but some warnnings exist like "JAVA_SAE_Warning: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ban call socket. yq30.javaruntime "